# The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Code First approach for my current application. I am facing an error while creating multiple related entites.

```
[Table("Project.WorkItems")]
public class WorkItem
{
    public WorkItem()
    {
        Links = new List<WorkItemLink>();
        States = new List<WorkItemStatus>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int WorkItemId { get; set; }
    [FieldRequired, StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [FieldRequired(FieldRequiredAttribute.FieldTypes.Select), StringLength(100)]
    public string Iteration { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    [FieldRequired(FieldRequiredAttribute.FieldTypes.Select), StringLength(128), Display(Name = "Assigned To")]
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    [FieldRequired(FieldRequiredAttribute.FieldTypes.Select)]
    public int ActivityType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime AddedOnDate { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkItemLink> Links { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkItemStatus> States { get; set; }
}

[Table("Projects.WorkItemStatus")]
public class WorkItemStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public int WorkItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual WorkItem WorkItem { get; set; }
    public int ItemStatus { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentStatus { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
}
```

FUNCTION THAT USE TO ADD

```
public async Task<EntityCreationResult<Models.WorkItem>> CreateWorkItemAsync(Models.WorkItem workitem)
{
     try
     {
         //workitem.States = new List<Models.WorkItemStatus>();
          if (workitem.Status == (int)Common.Helpers.Enumerations.WorkItemStatus.InProgress)
            {
                workitem.States.Add(new Models.WorkItemStatus { ItemStatus = (int)Common.Helpers.Enumerations.WorkItemStatus.ToDo, IsCurrentStatus = false });
                workitem.States.Add(new Models.WorkItemStatus { ItemStatus = (int)Common.Helpers.Enumerations.WorkItemStatus.InProgress, IsCurrentStatus = true });
            }
            else
            {
                workitem.States.Add(new Models.WorkItemStatus { ItemStatus = (int)Common.Helpers.Enumerations.WorkItemStatus.ToDo, IsCurrentStatus = true });
            }
         var result = await Context.WorkItemRepository.AddAsync(workitem);
         await Context.CommitChangesAsync();
         if (result.Succeeded)
             return result;
         throw new Exception("Failed To Create Work Item");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw;
     }
 }



public async Task<EntityCreationResult<T>> AddAsync<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew<EntityCreationResult<T>>(() =>
        {
            if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            if (Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
            }
            Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);

            return new EntityCreationResult<T>(entity);
        });
}
```

Model Creation

```
private void BuildRelationShips(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkItem>().HasMany<WorkItemLink>(s => s.Links)
             .WithRequired(s => s.WorkItem).HasForeignKey(s => s.WorkItemId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkItem>().HasMany<WorkItemStatus>(s => s.States)
            .WithRequired(s => s.WorkItem).HasForeignKey(s => s.WorkItemId);
        }
```

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred  while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might
>   be in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential
>   integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that
>   define the referential constraints are not consistent between
>   principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `IsCurrentStatus` i am just changing that in local list before perform add to database

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have updated the Question. Added `Model Creation` Details

Comment: i have completely changed it. Not using `FirstOrDefault` anymore but still getting the same issue

Comment: @HenkHolterman any idea ???

Comment: actually `WorkItem` inserted into database but not the related entites.